# How to move live QEMU-KVM VM without libvirt?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, qemu

Let me start by saying that I read [How to (properly) back up a live QEMU/KVM VM?](https://serverfault.com/questions/530848/how-to-properly-back-up-a-live-qemu-kvm-vm) But it does not seem to meet my need.

I am looking for a solution to backup AND move a few QEMU-KVM VMs without stopping them. The state do not need to be perfecting preserved (i.e. I don't care about their state after backup) but the backup must not be corrupted. I have no libvirt in the setup.

I have done so far: backup a powered off VM and move it to another host. This can be done easily by copying the .qcow2 disk images. But how can I do it without powering off VMs? Can I take a snapshot and then tell QEMU to only copy up to the snapshot? The snapshot method used is internal (using the same disk image), I would like to keep it that way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your life **really easy** and you can afford to run a `testing` distribution, than upgrade to Debian `bookworm` (it will migrate into stable at some point). That has made my QEMU/KVM life a lot easier, since `bookworm` comes with QEMU 6.1.

You can backup a life-VM with the simple command:

```
virsh backup-begin YourVM
```

If you have a fast disk (e.g. NVMe) that whole process will finish in less than a minute while the VM is running and not even slowing down much. You will find your Backup-VM in the default directory: `/var/lib/libvirt/images/` with a Unix-timestamp added to it. Make sure you also save the YourVM.xml file in `/etc/libvirt/qemu/` together with your backup for later restoration. You can simply start that image later - works like a charm for me.

You can also check the documentation [here](https://libvirt.org/kbase/live_full_disk_backup.html). According to the docs, backup should work with QEMU 5.2 in Debian bullseye too, but that did not work for me.